# How does Antivirus identify virus using signature-base?

Tags: antivirus, antimalware

I have read many articles about AV signature-based but I'm still not clear how AV using Hash to compared with the signature.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the precise difference between a signature based vs behavior based antivirus?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/95186), [File signature vs Virus signature](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/154051), [What patterns does a signature based anti-virus look for?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/51306/), ... - If these don't answer your question please me more specific than *"I'm still not clear"* when asking and show what exactly you don't understand.